# Find all point pairs closer than a given maximum distance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coordinates, distance

I want to find (efficiently) all pairs of points that are closer than some distance `max_d`. My current method, using `cdist`, is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def close_pairs(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)

    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    IJ  = np.sort(np.vstack((I,J)), axis=0)

    # remove diagonal element
    IJ  = IJ[:,np.diff(IJ,axis=0).ravel()<>0]

    # remove duplicate
    dt = np.dtype([('i',int),('j',int)])
    pairs = np.unique(IJ.T.view(dtype=dt)).view(int).reshape(-1,2)

    return pairs

def test():
    X = np.random.rand(100,2)*20
    p = close_pairs(X,2)

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1],'.r')
    plt.plot(X[p,0].T,X[p,1].T,'-b')
```

But I think this is overkill (and not very readable), because most of the work is done only to remove distance-to-self  and duplicates.

**My main question is:** is there a better way to do it?

(Note: the type of outputs (`array`, `set`, ...) is not important at this point)

My current thinking is on using `pdist` which returns a condensed distance array which contains only the right pairs. However, once I found the suitable coordinates `k`'s from the condensed distance array, how do I compute which `i,j` pairs it is equivalent to?

**So the alternative question is:** is there an easy way to get the list of coordinate pairs relative to the entries of `pdist` outputs:

- a function `f(k)->i,j`
- such that `cdist(X,X)[i,j] = pdist(X)[k]`

Comment: Would be awesome if you could just add a line of code to call `close_pairs` with some random data of the right shape and dtype, just so things are crystal clear :)

Comment: I added `python` to the tags and it now does the syntax highlighting here. In your actual problem, how many points are you dealing with? And do you need this calculation once, do you need to calculate it in a loop, do you need to calculate the result for multiple distances or multiple point sets? I've added an answer but what's best to do depends on the use case...

Comment: For my current need, it should be done once.

Comment: The number of point is typically somewhere in [1000,2000]

Comment: OK will look at timings when I'm back at my work machine. Personally I don't think there's much in it time-wise and would go with whatever method is most likely to be readable and bug-free. If it were my code I'd go with the kdtree method. If your scipy is out of date, I strongly recommend to install the Anaconda Python distribution.

Comment: I edited my answer a lot, so it gives you the function, to get the right i,j values, but it is quite slow

Comment: I made an answer for timeit comparison. Could you just update it with the ckdtree? I think the kdtree is the best approach in theory but for now (without c-compile version) it is too slow w.r.t. the other methods.

Comment: @Juh_ i am new to bumpy, how to do it, without removing the diagonal  element, in case I don't want to filter the case in which the pair can be alone if no other pair is close, if I remove this line  IJ  = IJ[:,np.diff(IJ,axis=0).ravel()<>0] it doesn't work, I couldn't figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, there are two fastest ways to find neighbor lists in 3D.  One is to use a most naive double-for-loop code written in C++ or Cython (in my case, both). It runs in N^2, but is very fast for small systems. The other way is to use a linear time algorithm. Scipy ckdtree is a good choice, but has limitations. Neighbor list finders from molecular dynamics software are most powerful, but are very hard to wrap, and likely have slow initialization time.

Below I compare four methods:

- Naive cython code
- Wrapper around [OpenMM](https://simtk.org/home/openmm) (is very hard to install, see below)
- `Scipy.spatial.ckdtree`
- `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`

Test setup: `n` points scattered in a rectangular box at volume density 0.2. System size ranging from 10 to a 1000000 (a million) particles. Contact radius is taken from `0.5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 10`. Note that because density is 0.2, at contact radius 0.5 we'll have on average about 0.1 contacts per particle, at 1 = 0.8, at 2 = 6.4, and at 10 - about 800! Contact finding was repeated several times for small systems, done once for systems >30k particles. If time per call exceeded 5 seconds, the run was aborted.

Setup: dual xeon 2687Wv3, 128GB RAM, Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.11, scipy 0.16.0, numpy 1.10.1.  None of the code was using parallel optimizations (except for OpenMM, though parallel part went so quick that it was not even noticeable on a CPU graph, most of the time was spend piping data to-from OpenMM).

**Results:** Note that plots below are logscale, and spread over 6 orders of magnitude. Even small visual difference may be actually 10-fold. 
For systems less than 1000 particles, `Cython` code was always faster. However, after 1000 particles results are dependent on the contact radius. `pdist` implementation was always slower than cython, and takes much more memory, because it explicitly creates a distance matrix, which is slow because of sqrt.

- At small contact radius (<1 contact per particle), `ckdtree` is a good choice for all system sizes.
- At medium contact radius, (5-50 contacts per particle) naive cython implementation is the best up to 10000 particles, then OpenMM starts to win by about several orders of magnitude, but `ckdtree` performs just 3-10 times worse
- At high contact radius (>200 contacts per particle) naive methods work up to 100k or 1M particles, then OpenMM may win.

Installing OpenMM is very tricky; you can read more in http://bitbucket.org/mirnylab/openmm-polymer file "contactmaps.py" or in the readme. However, the results below show that it is only advantageous for 5-50 contacts per particle, for N>100k particles.

[image]

Cython code below:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "<vector>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass vector[T]:
        cppclass iterator:
            T operator*()
            iterator operator++()
            bint operator==(iterator)
            bint operator!=(iterator)
        vector()
        void push_back(T&)
        T& operator[](int)
        T& at(int)
        iterator begin()
        iterator end()

np.import_array() # initialize C API to call PyArray_SimpleNewFromData
cdef public api tonumpyarray(int* data, long long size) with gil:
    if not (data and size >= 0): raise ValueError
    cdef np.npy_intp dims = size
    #NOTE: it doesn't take ownership of `data`. You must free `data` yourself
    return np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &dims, np.NPY_INT, <void*>data)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def contactsCython(inArray, cutoff):
    inArray = np.asarray(inArray, dtype = np.float64, order = "C")
    cdef int N = len(inArray)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] data = inArray
    cdef int j,i
    cdef double curdist
    cdef double cutoff2 = cutoff * cutoff  # IMPORTANT to avoid slow sqrt calculation
    cdef vector[int] contacts1
    cdef vector[int] contacts2
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1, N):
            curdist = (data[i,0] - data[j,0]) **2 +(data[i,1] - data[j,1]) **2 + (data[i,2] - data[j,2]) **2
            if curdist < cutoff2:
                contacts1.push_back(i)
                contacts2.push_back(j)
    cdef int M = len(contacts1)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim = 2] contacts = np.zeros((M,2), dtype = np.int32)
    for i in range(M):
        contacts[i,0] = contacts1[i]
        contacts[i,1] = contacts2[i]
    return contacts
```

Compilation (or makefile) for Cython code:

```
    cython --cplus fastContacts.pyx
    g++  -g -march=native -Ofast -fpic -c   fastContacts.cpp -o fastContacts.o `python-config --includes`
    g++  -g -march=native -Ofast -shared  -o fastContacts.so  fastContacts.o `python-config --libs`
```

Testing code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import signal
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ckdtree
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

from contactmaps import giveContactsOpenMM  # remove this unless you have OpenMM and openmm-polymer libraries installed
from fastContacts import contactsCython


class TimeoutException(Exception): pass


@contextmanager
def time_limit(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutException("Timed out!")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)


matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})


def close_pairs_ckdtree(X, max_d):
    tree = ckdtree.cKDTree(X)
    pairs = tree.query_pairs(max_d)
    return np.array(list(pairs))


def condensed_to_pair_indices(n, k):
    x = n - (4. * n ** 2 - 4 * n - 8 * k + 1) ** .5 / 2 - .5
    i = x.astype(int)
    j = k + i * (i + 3 - 2 * n) / 2 + 1
    return np.array([i, j]).T


def close_pairs_pdist(X, max_d):
    d = pdist(X)
    k = (d < max_d).nonzero()[0]
    return condensed_to_pair_indices(X.shape[0], k)


a = np.random.random((100, 3)) * 3  # test set
methods = {"cython": contactsCython, "ckdtree": close_pairs_ckdtree, "OpenMM": giveContactsOpenMM,
           "pdist": close_pairs_pdist}

# checking that each method gives the same value
allUniqueInds = []
for ind, method in methods.items():
    contacts = method(a, 1)
    uniqueInds = contacts[:, 0] + 100 * contacts[:, 1]  # unique index of each contacts
    allUniqueInds.append(np.sort(uniqueInds))  # adding sorted unique conatcts
for j in allUniqueInds:
    assert np.allclose(j, allUniqueInds[0])

# now actually doing testing
repeats = [30,30,30, 30, 30, 20,  20,   10,   5,   3,     2 ,       1,     1,      1]
sizes =    [10,30,100, 200, 300,  500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000, 300000, 1000000]
systems = [[np.random.random((n, 3)) * ((n / 0.2) ** 0.333333) for k in range(repeat)] for n, repeat in
           zip(sizes, repeats)]

for j, radius in enumerate([0.5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 10]):
    plt.subplot(2, 3, j + 1)
    plt.title("Radius = {0}; {1:.2f} cont per particle".format(radius, 0.2 * (4 / 3 * np.pi * radius ** 3)))

    times = {i: [] for i in methods}

    for name, method in methods.items():
        for n, system, repeat in zip(sizes, systems, repeats):
            if name == "pdist" and n > 30000:
                break  # memory issues
            st = time.time()
            try:
                with time_limit(5 * repeat):
                    for ind in range(repeat):
                        k = len(method(system[ind], radius))
            except:
                print("Run aborted")
                break
            end = time.time()
            mytime = (end - st) / repeat
            times[name].append((n, mytime))
            print("{0} radius={1} n={2} time={3} repeat={4} contPerParticle={5}".format(name, radius, n, mytime,repeat, 2 * k / n))

    for name in sorted(times.keys()):
        plt.plot(*zip(*times[name]), label=name)
    plt.xscale("log")
    plt.yscale("log")
    plt.xlabel("System size")
    plt.ylabel("Time (seconds)")
    plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like ckdtree shipped with scipy 0.17 will have an option to return a numpy array. This should make it much faster on huge contact lists, as it will avoid conversion from a set to a list to a numpy array.

Comment: As of now, scipy ckdtree with return option of np.ndarray is my default way to find nearest neighbors in 3D. I have deprecated any other contact finders in our polymer simulation library.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it with the cKDTree module. See [query_pairs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.spatial import ckdtree


def close_pairs(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)

    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    IJ  = np.sort(np.vstack((I,J)), axis=0)

    # remove diagonal element
    IJ  = IJ[:,np.diff(IJ,axis=0).ravel()<>0]

    # remove duplicate
    dt = np.dtype([('i',int),('j',int)])
    pairs = np.unique(IJ.T.view(dtype=dt)).view(int).reshape(-1,2)

    return pairs

def close_pairs_ckdtree(X, max_d):
    tree = ckdtree.cKDTree(X)
    pairs = tree.query_pairs(max_d)
    return np.array(list(pairs))

def test():
    np.random.seed(0)
    X = np.random.rand(100,2)*20
    p = close_pairs(X,2)
    q = close_pairs_ckdtree(X, 2)

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1],'.r')
    plt.plot(X[p,0].T,X[p,1].T,'-b')
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1],'.r')
    plt.plot(X[q,0].T,X[q,1].T,'-b')

    plt.show()

t
```

Comment: With scipy 0.11, I have to use the KDtree version, which is relatively slow. How is it with ckdtree?

Comment: I don't have any numbers, but i know from experience that it makes a big difference (as you would expect)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it myself. The function converting indices `k` in condensed distance array to equivalent `i,j` in square distance array is:

```
def condensed_to_pair_indices(n,k):
    x = n-(4.*n**2-4*n-8*k+1)**.5/2-.5
    i = x.astype(int)
    j = k+i*(i+3-2*n)/2+1
    return i,j
```

I had to play a little with `sympy` to find it. Now, to compute all point pairs than are less than a given distance apart:

```
def close_pairs_pdist(X,max_d):
    d = pdist(X)
    k = (d<max_d).nonzero()[0]
    return condensed_to_pair_indices(X.shape[0],k)
```

As expected, it is more efficient than the other methods (but I did not test [ckdtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286036/1206998)). I will update the [timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288792/1206998) answer.

Comment: nice, i found the formula to go the other direction, but to invert it combinatorics had been a while too long ago ;-)

Answer (score 1):

slightly faster, didnt test the time difference thoroughly, but if i ran it a few times, it gave a time of about 0.0755529403687 for my method, and  0.0928771495819 for yours. I use the triu method to get rid of upper triangle of the array (where duplicates are) including diagonal (which is where the self-distances are), and i dont sort either, since if you plot it, it does not matter if i plot them in order or not. So i guess it speeds up about 15% or so

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.misc import comb

def close_pairs(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)
    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    IJ  = np.sort(np.vstack((I,J)), axis=0)

    # remove diagonal element
    IJ  = IJ[:,np.diff(IJ,axis=0).ravel()<>0]

    # remove duplicate
    dt = np.dtype([('i',int),('j',int)])
    pairs = np.unique(IJ.T.view(dtype=dt)).view(int).reshape(-1,2)

    return pairs


def close_pairs1(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)
    d1 = np.triu_indices(len(X)) # indices of the upper triangle including the diagonal
    d[d1] = max_d+1 # value that will not get selected when doing d<max_d in the next line
    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    pairs = np.vstack((I,J)).T
    return pairs

def close_pairs3(X, max_d):
    d = pdist(X)
    n = len(X)
    pairs = np.zeros((0,2))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            # formula from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html
            a=d[int(comb(n,2)-comb(n-i,2)+j-i-1+0.1)] # the +0.1 is because otherwise i get floating point trouble
            if(a<max_d):
                pairs = np.r_[pairs, np.array([i,j])[None,:]]
    return pairs

def close_pairs4(X, max_d):
    d = pdist(X)
    n = len(X)
    a = np.where(d<max_d)[0]
    i = np.arange(n)[:,None]
    j = np.arange(n)[None,:]
    b = np.array(comb(n,2)-comb(n-i,2)+j-i-1+0.1, dtype=int)
    d1 = np.tril_indices(n)
    b[d1] = -1

    pairs = np.zeros((0,2), dtype=int)

    # next part is the bottleneck: the np.where each time, 
    for v in a:
        i, j = np.where(v==b) 
        pairs = np.r_[pairs, np.array([i[0],j[0]])[None,:]]
    return pairs

def close_pairs5(X, max_d):
    t0=time.time()
    d = pdist(X)
    n = len(X)
    a = np.where(d<max_d)[0]
    i = np.arange(n)[:,None]
    j = np.arange(n)[None,:]
    t1 = time.time()
    b = np.array(comb(n,2)-comb(n-i,2)+j-i-1+0.1, dtype=int)
    d1 = np.tril_indices(n)
    b[d1] = -1
    t2 = time.time()
    V = b[:,:,None]-a[None,None,:] # takes a little time
    t3 = time.time()
    p = np.where(V==0) # takes most of the time, thought that removing the for-loop from the previous method might improve it, but it does not do that much. This method contains the formula you wanted though, but apparently it is still faster if you use the cdist methods
    t4 = time.time()
    pairs = np.vstack((p[0],p[1])).T
    print t4-t3,t3-t2, t2-t1, t1-t0
    return pairs





def test():
    X = np.random.rand(1000,2)*20
    import time
    t0 = time.time()
    p = close_pairs(X,2)
    t1 = time.time()
    p2 = close_pairs1(X,2)
    t2 = time.time()
    print t2-t1, t1-t0

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1],'.r')
    plt.plot(X[p,0].T,X[p,1].T,'-b')
    plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1],'.r')
    plt.plot(X[p2,0].T,X[p2,1].T,'-b')
    plt.show()



test()
```

NOTE: plotting laggs if you do it for 1K points, but it needs 1K points to compare speeds, but i checked that it works correctly when plotting it if doing it with 100 points
The speed difference is something like ten to twenty percent, and i think it will not get much better than this, since i got rid of all the sorting and unique elements things, so the part that takes most of the time probably is the `d = cdist(X, X)` line

Edit: some more testing shows that  in those times, that cdist line takes up about 0.065 sec, while the rest for your method is about 0.02 and for me about 0.015 sec or so. Conclusion: the main bottleneck of your code is the `d = cdist(X, X)` line, and the stuff i changed speeds up the rest of the code you got, but the main bottleneck stays

Edit: added the method close_pairs3, which gives you the formula, but speed blows, (still need to figure out how to invert that formula, and than it will be superfast, will do that tomorrow - will use np.where(pdist(X)

Edit: added method close_pairs4, which is slightly better than 3, and explains what happens, but is veeery slow, and same with method 5, does not have that for-loop, but is still very slow

Comment: My solution is not that slow, so the time gain is not the most important. However, being more readable (and still faster) is a good thing.

Comment: @Juh_ well, i guess my code is a bit shorter and more readable?

Comment: That's what I meant :-)

Comment: I think you should post the `close_pairs3` in a different answer. Now, doing 2 loops and concatenating array at each step can only be slow (at least you should use `set` instead of concatenation, or doing the concatenation once at the end). But thanks for this formula.

Comment: However, there you compute `k` from `i,j`. To be efficient, it is the opposite that should be done.

Comment: @Juh_ yeah, still thinking about inverting that (or at least in a way that works faster than how it is now, since algorithmically its simple)

Answer (score 0):

I made some code to compare the proposed solutions.

Note: I use scipy 0.11 and cannot use the ckdtree solution (only kdtree) which I expect to be slower. Could anyone with scipy v0.12+ run this code?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
from scipy.spatial import ckdtree
from scipy.spatial import kdtree


def close_pairs(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)

    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    IJ  = np.sort(np.vstack((I,J)), axis=0)

    # remove diagonal element
    IJ  = IJ[:,np.diff(IJ,axis=0).ravel()<>0]

    # remove duplicate
    dt = np.dtype([('i',int),('j',int)])
    pairs = np.unique(IJ.T.view(dtype=dt)).view(int).reshape(-1,2)

    return pairs


def condensed_to_pair_indices(n,k):
    x = n-(4.*n**2-4*n-8*k+1)**.5/2-.5
    i = x.astype(int)
    j = k+i*(i+3-2*n)/2+1
    return i,j

def close_pairs_pdist(X,max_d):
    d = pdist(X)
    k = (d<max_d).nonzero()[0]
    return condensed_to_pair_indices(X.shape[0],k)


def close_pairs_triu(X,max_d):
    d = cdist(X,X)
    d1 = np.triu_indices(len(X)) # indices of the upper triangle including the diagonal
    d[d1] = max_d+1 # value that will not get selected when doing d<max_d in the next line
    I,J = (d<max_d).nonzero()
    pairs = np.vstack((I,J)).T
    return pairs

def close_pairs_ckdtree(X, max_d):
    tree = ckdtree.cKDTree(X)
    pairs = tree.query_pairs(max_d)
    return pairs       # remove the conversion as it is not required

def close_pairs_kdtree(X, max_d):
    tree  = kdtree.KDTree(X)
    pairs = tree.query_pairs(max_d)
    return pairs       # remove the conversion as it is not required


methods = [close_pairs, close_pairs_pdist, close_pairs_triu, close_pairs_kdtree] #, close_pairs_ckdtree]

def time_test(n=[10,50,100], max_d=[5,10,50], iter_num=100):
    import timeit

    for method in methods:
        print '-- time using ' + method.__name__ + ' ---'
        for ni in n:
            for d in max_d:
                setup = '\n'.join(['import numpy as np','import %s' % __name__,'np.random.seed(0)','X = np.random.rand(%d,2)*100'%ni])
                stmt  = 'close_pairs.%s(X,%f)' % (method.__name__,d)
                time  = timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=setup, number=iter_num)/iter_num
                print 'n=%3d, max_d=%2d: \t%.2fms' % (ni, d,time*1000)
```

Output of `time_test(iter_num=10,n=[20,100,500],max_d=[1,5,10])` are:

```
-- time using close_pairs ---
n= 20, max_d= 1:    0.22ms
n= 20, max_d= 5:    0.16ms
n= 20, max_d=10:    0.21ms
n=100, max_d= 1:    0.41ms
n=100, max_d= 5:    0.53ms
n=100, max_d=10:    0.97ms
n=500, max_d= 1:    7.12ms
n=500, max_d= 5:    12.28ms
n=500, max_d=10:    33.41ms
-- time using close_pairs_pdist ---
n= 20, max_d= 1:    0.11ms
n= 20, max_d= 5:    0.10ms
n= 20, max_d=10:    0.11ms
n=100, max_d= 1:    0.19ms
n=100, max_d= 5:    0.19ms
n=100, max_d=10:    0.19ms
n=500, max_d= 1:    2.31ms
n=500, max_d= 5:    2.82ms
n=500, max_d=10:    2.49ms
-- time using close_pairs_triu ---
n= 20, max_d= 1:    0.17ms
n= 20, max_d= 5:    0.16ms
n= 20, max_d=10:    0.16ms
n=100, max_d= 1:    0.83ms
n=100, max_d= 5:    0.80ms
n=100, max_d=10:    0.80ms
n=500, max_d= 1:    23.64ms
n=500, max_d= 5:    22.87ms
n=500, max_d=10:    22.96ms
-- time using close_pairs_kdtree ---
n= 20, max_d= 1:    1.71ms
n= 20, max_d= 5:    1.69ms
n= 20, max_d=10:    1.96ms
n=100, max_d= 1:    34.99ms
n=100, max_d= 5:    35.47ms
n=100, max_d=10:    34.91ms
n=500, max_d= 1:    253.87ms
n=500, max_d= 5:    255.05ms
n=500, max_d=10:    256.66ms
```

Conclusion:

- The overall fastest method is  [close_pairs_pdist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21313994/1206998)
- The initial method is relatively fast, but sensitive to both the number of samples and the percentage of pairs to return
- both the [close_pairs_triu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286644/1206998) and [close_pairs_kdtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286036/1206998) are sensitive to the number of samples but relatively insensitive to the number of outputs.
- the [close_pairs_triu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286644/1206998) method is much faster than [close_pairs_kdtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286036/1206998)

However, the [ckdtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286036/1206998) method needs to be tested.