# Identifying pairs of Python array cells separated by maximum distance in a large array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distance

I have raster containing spatial ecological habitat data which I've converted to a 2-dimensional numpy array. In this array, values of 1 = data, and 0 = no data. 
From this data I want to **generate an array of containing all data cell pairs where the distance between each cell is less than a maximum Euclidean cutoff distance** (i.e. 2 cells apart).

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285058/find-all-point-pairs-closer-than-a-given-maximum-distance) useful, but the answers there appear to first measure all pairwise distances, then subsequently threshold the results by a maximum cutoff. My datasets are large (over 1 million data cells in a 13500*12000 array), so any pairwise distance measure that tries to calculate distances between *all* pairs of cells will fail: I need a solution which somehow stops looking for possible neighbours outside of a certain search radius (or something similar).

I've experimented with `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`, but so far haven't had luck applying it to either my two-dimensional data, or finding a way to prevent `pdist` from calculating distances between even distant pairs of cells. I've attached an example array and a desired output array for maximum Euclidean cutoff distance = 2 cells:

[image: Example array and desired output]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example 2-D habitat array (1 = data)
example_array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot example array
plt.imshow(example_array, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: A simple algorithm is: iterate over every data point (r, c); take a slice array[r-D:r+D, c-D:c+D]; append the indices of any data points in that slice to your results. That may be too slow for your dataset though. This algorithm uses the "Manhattan" distance between points. If you need Euclidean, you can pre-calculate a mask to apply to the slice.

Comment: For each cell you could search the neighboring cells within the radius of interest. If your array is indexed (i, j) and max_radius is 2, iterating from the cell index to cell index [+2, +1, 0, -1, -2] for both i and j, except when i=j. if you need the closest pairs, use a BFS with a cut off when you reach max_radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to confess my numpy is weak -- maybe there is a way to do it directly.  Nonetheless, the problem is not difficult in pure Python.  The following code will output pairs of x/y coordinates of your matching data.  There are a lot of potential optimizations that could obscure the code and make it go faster, but given the size of your data set and the size (2.0) of your example radius, I doubt any of those are worthwhile (with the possible exception of creating numpy views into the arrays instead of sublists).

**Updated** -- The code has had a couple of bugs fixed -- (1) it was looking too far to the left on lines that were below the starting point, and (2) it was not doing the right thing near the left edge.  The invocation of the function now uses a radius of 2.5 to show how additional pairs can be picked up.

```
example_array = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def findpairs(mylist, radius = 2.0):
    """
    Find pairs with data within a given radius.
    If we work from the top of the array down, we never
    need to look up (because we already would have found
    those, and we never need to look left on the same line.
    """

    # Create the parameters of a half circle, which is
    # the relative beginning and ending X coordinates to
    # search for each Y line starting at this one and
    # working down.  To avoid duplicates and extra work,
    # not only do we not look up, we never look left on
    # the same line as what we are matching, but we do
    # on subsequent lines.

    semicircle = []
    x = 1
    while x:
        y = len(semicircle)
        x = int(max(0, (radius ** 2 - y ** 2)) ** 0.5)
        # Don't look back on same line...
        semicircle.append((-x if y else 1, x + 1))

    # The maximum number of y lines we will search
    # at a time.
    max_y = len(semicircle)

    for y_start in range(len(mylist)):
        sublists = enumerate(mylist[y_start:y_start + max_y], y_start)
        sublists = zip(semicircle, sublists)
        check = (x for (x, value) in enumerate(mylist[y_start]) if value)
        for x_start in check:
            for (x_lo, x_hi), (y, ylist) in sublists:
                # Deal with left edge problem
                x_lo = max(0, x_lo + x_start)
                xlist = ylist[x_lo: x_start + x_hi]
                for x, value in enumerate(xlist, x_lo):
                    if value:
                        yield (x_start, y_start), (x, y)

print(list(findpairs(example_array, 2.5)))
```

Execution time is going to be highly data dependent.  For grins, I created arrays of the size you specified (13500 x 12000) to test timing.  I used a bigger radius (3.0 instead of 2.0) and tried two cases:  no matches, and every match.  To avoid reallocating lists over and over, I simply ran the iterator and tossed the results.  The code to do that is below.  For a best-case (empty) array, it ran on my machine in 7 seconds; the time for the worst-case (all 1s) array was around 12 minutes.

```
def dummy(val):
    onelist = 13500 * [val]
    listolists = 12000 * [onelist]

    for i in findpairs(listolists, 3.0):
      pass

dummy(0)
dummy(1)
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, this looks fantastic, thankyou! One problem: I've converted the list generated by your code above to an igraph network for visualisation, and several edges seem to be missing. I've attached an image below: blue highlights are short links on the left boundary of the array which are completely missed, and yellow and green highlights are longer links which are only being identified in certain directions (in this case, SSE and ESE links are missed, while SSW and WSW links are picked up): http://imgur.com/XR5IstM (output for example above; max distance = 2)

Comment: (1) The left edge is a bug I understand but will have to figure out a fix for.  (3) The "missing" green and yellow links are actually bugs in (a) the SSW/WSW direction (for which the fix is easy), and (b) my understanding of your problem.  Those are longer than "2.0" from point to point.   How do you want the distance calculated?

Comment: All known bugs fixed (answer updated) but you need to figure out how to specify the radius, I think.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the update. It now works really well. You were also correct about the longer links in the example above: the SSW/WSW links should indeed not have been included for a 2 radius limit. They now only show up for radii above ~2.5, which is perfect.